# Google App Engine fails to launch in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine

I'm having trouble launching Google App Engine in eclipse.

I created a new "Maven-based Google App Engine Standard Java Project" with the [Google Cloud Tools](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/creating-new-webapp) plugin for Eclipse by selecting the "Hello World template".

I then tried to launch the application by right-clicking on the project in the Package Explorer, and choosing the option "Run As > App Engine".

The application fails to launch.  The following stack trace appears in the Error Log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.appengine.localserver.launching.LaunchHelper.findExistingServers(LaunchHelper.java:110)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.appengine.localserver.launching.LaunchHelper.launch(LaunchHelper.java:61)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.appengine.localserver.launching.LocalAppEngineStandardLaunchShortcut.launch(LocalAppEngineStandardLaunchShortcut.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension.launch(LaunchShortcutExtension.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.LaunchShortcutAction.run(LaunchShortcutAction.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.LaunchShortcutAction.runWithEvent(LaunchShortcutAction.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
```

Here's my session data:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.5.2.M20160212-1500
java.version=1.8.0_111
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
```

What am I missing?  Is another step required to get the application to launch successfully?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

NPEs should never happen, and from looking at the code, it would seem that you have a corrupt server definition. You could open the *Servers* view and remove any corrupt servers and then try again.

But before doing so, if you wouldn't mind, we would first appreciate you providing more details on this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/1852) to include your `.../.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/servers.xml` file, the screenshot of the *Servers* view, and the exact steps to reproduce, so that we can fix it.

Comment: I had a server from the old [Google Plugin for Eclipse](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/) hanging around.  Removing this server does indeed fix the problem.  Sorry, but I removed it before I saw your comment.  Consequently, I am not able to provide you with the old servers.xml file.

Comment: We were able to reproduce and the fix will be in the next release.  Thanks for the follow-up!